# Creating Directory in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've looked this question on the web but there isn't any "direct" answer to it that was suitable to me. My app is downloading some videos from the url typed in a `TextField`. I'm using `flutter_donwloader` package. The error displayed because I haven't created a directory is:

```
 'package:flutter_downloader/src/downloader.dart': Failed assertion: line 70 pos 12:
 'Directory(savedDir).existsSync()': is not true
```

I want to save it in the Downloads folder. I actually don't know how to create a directory and this is why I haven't been able to understand other answers. Please help guys.

Comment: What is the target platform for your app?

Comment: android 11, api level 30

Comment: Have you checked the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader/example) for the package on pub.dev?

Comment: man i didn't look at it i don't know how did i noti think it'll work now. will update you